# Quick questions about summation notation used in my book

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, notation

**My Questions**

1. In the screenshot below, is the summation notation in the orange (top) box and blue (bottom) box the exact same? So in a $3$ by $3$ matrix you'd only want to sum $a_{12} + a_{13} + a_{23}$.
2. Is it correct to say that the orange box is exactly the same as
   $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} \sum_{j = i + 1}^n P(A_i A_j)?$$
3. Is it correct to say that the BLUE box is exactly the same as
   $$\sum_{(i,j):i<j} E[\min(X_i,X_j)]?$$
4. Why would you choose one notation or the other? It seems the blue box is faster to write.
5. Is it correct to say that the following will always hold if $i$ and $j$ span the exact same indices and $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$ for all $i$ and $j$?
   $$\sum_{i \neq j} a_{ij} = 2\sum_{i<j} a_{ij}$$
   Thank you for your time and patience.

---

[image]

Comment: for 1. , 2. , 3. , 5. I would just say "you are correct". Talking about 4. , I don't think there is a preferable one, everything is ok until it is clear enough.

Comment: @LucaMac Thanks for your confirmation, since this summation notation shows up everywhere I want to make sure I have an exact understanding or it makes me feel uneasy when trying to learn new concepts. I wonder why the author of my book (who I admire quite a bit) jumps around with the notation... but I suppose you're right it just has to be clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your questions one by one.

1. Your interpretation is correct.
2. Yes.
3. Yes.
4. It depends, if the author is trying to emphasize the minimum property or if he is trying to emphasize what motivated the minimum property.
5. Correct again!

Great work making sure you really understand everything in the book!

Comment: Thanks appreciate your help. Math is hard enough without misunderstandings in notation

Comment: You are welcome! Best of wishes on your mathematical journey!